# Serviced Component interface not showing up

Tags: c#, com+, servicedcomponent

I created a Serviced Component to access emails stored in an SQL Server database. 
It only has one public method.I did apply the attributes mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20401469/why-is-my-com-object-not-displaying-methods-in-component-services)

When i open the component in my local Component services. I can see my ReadEmail interface(Version: 6.2 of Component Services)

But when i try to open it at the server I can't.(Version: 2001.12.4720.3959 of Component Services)

I'm using .NET 3.5

It suspect it may have something to with different versions of Component Services, but i have other components and they do show up correctly

Comment: Going for the obvious explanation you did not mention: did you actually run regsvcs.exe on that server machine?

Comment: yes @Hans. I figured it out.It was tough ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.
Turns out i was using a namespace that probably was used in another component.
I changed the namespace for my component and it worked